# How to concatenate array of matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have an array of possibly million 3x3 matrices. What would be the fastest way to horizontally concatenate them in MATLAB without using for loop? Ideally I would like 
to do something simple like this

```
 [M(:,:,1) M(:,:,2) ... M(:,:,10000000)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the way the question is put is to convert a big 3-D matrix `M(:,:,j)` to a concatenated 2-D one.
For that just use `reshape`, for example:

```
M=reshape(M,size(M,1),[]);
```